# Implement date Format similar to Java/C# (like "dddd/mm/yy")

Tags: javascript, regex

Overall I want to implement formatting function for JavaScript date values that accept strings similar to Java/C# formatting: "dddd/mm/yy" and like.

My current problem is scoped to - I have a string with 'd's. The string can be like

```
'd/dd/ddd/dddd'
'dd/d/ddd'
'dddd     ddd       /dd'
```

the gaps between d's can be single/more white-spaces or `:`(colon)  or `/` (slash) or all of them (may be one or two or three characters) at a time. Examples:

```
'dd/dddd:ddd  d'
'dd:/ddd d   d'
```

if it is

- one `d`, I should replace with `'somestring1'` (means I have some strings to replace that particular d's)
- two `d`'s, replace with `'someotherString2'`
- three `d`'s ,replace with `'someotherotherstring'`
- four  `d`'s ,replace with `'someotherotherotherstring'`

with respective spacing or with that `:`(colon) and `/`(slash)

I'm trying to use regular expression for that.

Comment: Do you have any problems with that?

Comment: yes, I'm doing that for date format

Comment: You should ask a question at the end of your post. Not just state your problem and end with thanks... What do you need ? have you already done something ? Show us what your problem is, and that's what @AlexeiLevenkov is telling you.

Comment: Also it is good idea to ask question about what you actually need to do, not how you may use regular expression for that. Now you need to accept nice xanatos' answer and go and ask the question again since you really want something different...

Comment: See if you ok with my edit of your question. Feel free to revert...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With two replaces it's easy:

```
var res = "'dd/dddd:ddd  d'".replace(/d(?![^d])/g, '0')
                            .replace('d', '1');
```

It means "replace all 'd' not followed by 'non-d' with 0", then replace all the remaining 'd' with 1.

You could even do it in another way:

```
var res = "'dd/dddd:ddd  d'".replace(/d(?=d)/g, '0')
                            .replace('d', '1');
```

It means "replace all 'd' followed by 'd' with 0", then replace all the remaining 'd' with 1.

If you want to use functions in replace you can do this:

```
var res = "'dd/dddd:ddd  d'".replace(/(d(?=d))|(d)/g, 
    function(match, p1, p2) { 
        return p1 ? '0' : '1'; 
    } 
);
```

The result is the same. We have two capturing groups, one for the 'd' followed by another 'd' and another for the remaining 'd'(s). These matches are passed to a function, that receives in `p1` and `p2` the captures. Clearly for every match only one of the captures (`p1` or `p2`) can be defined (because they are alternatives), so with the ternary operator `?` I check if `p1` has a value then I return `0`, otherwise I return `1`.

**For the changed question**

If you want to replace with an array of string you can do something like:

```
var replaces = [ "some1", "some2", "some3", "some4" ];

var res = "'dd/dddd:ddd  d ddddd'".replace(/d+/g, 
    function(match) { 
        return match.length - 1 < replaces.length ? // check if there is a substitution
            replaces[match.length - 1] : // if there is a substitution
            match; // otherwise leave the d(s)
    } 
);
```

Comment: +1. Nice answer to the question, also unlikely to help OP with parsing formatting strings...

Comment: Other possible solution would be the other way around `replace('/(d+)d/g', '$11').replace('d','0')`. I think your solution would be slightly better though, as it doesn't use a backreference.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Aaah... I hadn't noticed he had changed his request.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've mentioned this is for a date, I'm going to guess `1`, `01`, `001`, etc. aren't actually the only possible replacements.

So, you can find any single `d` or group of `d`'s with `/d+/`:

```
var revised = original.replace(/d+/, function (dees) {
    return // ...;
});
```

Within the `function`, you can test `dees.length` to determine which value to `return`.

For the examples you listed:

```
if (dees.length == 1) {
    return 'somestring1';
} else if (dees.length == 2) {
    return 'someotherString2';
} else if (dees.length == 3) {
    return 'someotherotherstring';
} else if (dees.length == 4) {
    return 'someotherotherotherstring';
}
```

You can also use an `Object` or `Array` to match up the `length` with a key or index.

```
var results = {
    1: 'somestring1',
    2: 'someotherString2',
    3: 'someotherotherstring',
    4: 'someotherotherotherstring'
];

return results[dees.length] || 'somethingelse';
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic formatting for numeric values may be handled without regex with much more straightforward code:

```
  var format = "dddd/ddd/dd/d";

  var result = format.replace("dddd", formatWithFourDigits(year))
                     .replace("ddd",  formatWithThreeDigits(year))
                     .replace("dd",   formatWithTwoDigits(year))
                     .replace("d",    formatWithOneDigits(year));
```

For more complex - tokenize string first and than map each token (like "dddd") to a function that performs formatting for that format. Tokenization can be done with regular expression similar to one shown in other answers...

Comment: see this complication I am now facing
var format = 'dddd/ddd/dd/d';
I want to replace dddd's with friday.
for first replace, it is working fine,
after the last replace,
the 'd' in friday also changing to some other value.
is there any other way?

Comment: @Lonely - yes - it is exactly what I tried to say: simple version works "for numeric values". You have 2 other answers showing you how tokenize the string and call function to replace each token... not sure why you find them not useful.

Comment: yours is a simple answer. will check the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Do your replacements from longest to shortest

`var output=input.replace(/dddd/g,"somestring4")
.replace(/ddd/g,"somestring3")
.replace(/dd/g,"somestring2")
.replace(/d/g,"somestring1")`

A problem with this is it will replace 5 consecutive dees with somestring4somestring1, but it's not clear what you want to happen in that case.